# How to avoid img error icon

Tags: html, image

If you give an src and it cannot find the img it usually appears a square with a X. Is there any way to avoid that? I mean if it cannot find the img, just show nothing

You can check your solution here:http://jsfiddle.net/GmBax/

HTML:

```
<img src="1.png" width="42" height="42" >
```

Comment: I would say, just upload the image with your html. then no cross or whatever would show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another option, you can load a default empty image on error. Ex: `<img src="/img.jpg" onerror="this.src='/none.jpg'" />`

Answer (score 0):

put in an "alt" and a "title" tag - this way if the image doesn't show, the alt text will show instead.

e.g.

```
<img src="1.png" width="42" height="42" alt="hello" title="hi">
```

Comment: you should add a title as well as an alt because alt doesn't work in firefox

Comment: `alt` and `title` have different semantics. Use them appropriately. Both work properly on my Firefox install - it shows the text specified in the `alt` attribute in place of the image, and the `title` text in the tooltip when hovering the mouse over it. Same behaviour in Chrome & IE.

Comment: I think it does not work in Safari, Chrome, IE? Check it here:http://jsfiddle.net/GmBax/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the alt parameter for example.. You can either add a text or leave it empty.

```
<img src="1.png" width="42" height="42" alt="" />
```

Or handle it by some PHP or whatever you're using.

Comment: I think it does not work in Safari, Chrome, IE? Check it here:jsfiddle.net/GmBax/2